# representing questionnaires in a django application

Tags: python, django

Hi

I want to make a site in django that has 64 different tests, each holding 15 different questions (which can be answered via checkboxes, there are 3 to 4 variants (A, B, C, D) to every question, and there can be more than one right answer). When the user presses "Check", the submitted answers are compared to the right ones, and a score is displayed.

My question is, how should i represent the 64 tests with 15 questions each in a django app? Should i make 64 different models for each test, each containing 15 CharFields with the right answers? And then another 64 models each containing 15 CharFields where the answer from the user will be stored. And then the two sets of models will be compared to each other? I'm sorry for the silly question, but it's my first time writing an interactive web application and i'm quite confused.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model is a class. You wouldn't make 64 classes if your programme was to have 64 objects in any other context.

Create one class, modelling a generic question, then create instances. Likewise, create one class to represent quizzes, aggregating questions.

Comment: but there can be either 2, 3 or 4 answers to a question. Should i then create 3 different classes, each modelling a question with different number of answers?

Comment: @geekkid Have the one class cope with an arbitrary number of answers.